# How to remove a file from a git repository, without deleting it in cloned repositories

Tags: git

I can remove a file from a git repository with

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

But when I pull these changes in a cloned directory, this file will be deleted there.

Is it possible avoid this without saving this file in all clones and restore it after pulling?

Comment: *git rm <file>*, *commit*, *push*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `assume-unchanged` flag.

Basically, try running the following command

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

This will stop tracking any local changes to the `file`.

To undo the effect of above command, use `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged`

Comment: If you pull after this, will it overwrite your file? And can you then remove the file without it being removed from other repos cloned from the same origin?

Answer (score -1):

The idea of a clone of a repository is that it is meant to be the same, so pulling will always make the two repos the same. 
If you want to have two different sets of files you could create a new branch with the deleted file gone using

```
git checkout -b <branch_name>
```

and then commit the deleted file there.

If you really don't want to do this you could always pull the changes and then easily get the file back by using

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- <file>
```

Which checks out the file from the commit before last.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is, that I had a config file included, which should be removed from the repository, since it may be host dependent (and should never have been added). I don't know exactly, where this repository is used, and I like to avoid deleting this file (and breaking a running configuration) when pulled elsewhere.

Comment: I would store an example config file in the git repository and add the actual config file (which may contain passwords) to .gitignore

Comment: Yes, if the config file is host dependant then each host will have to set it up from the example file. Git should only be used for files you want to version control.

Comment: The problem is that the file is already tracked in master. You want to remove it from master without it being deleted elsewhere if you pull.